# Correct way to measure a 4-20mA sensor?

Tags: voltage-measurement, 4-20ma

I have an 0-10V analog input channel that I would also like to measure 4-20mA sensors. I have added a 500 ohm shunt resistor I can jumper in when I am using the 4-20mA instead of the 0-10. Can this be done and is it the best way to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: The best solution is probably a current-to-voltage converter. You just need an op amp and a few resistors (or an in-amp if you want something more independent of the current loop's voltage).

Comment: @Hearth I am trying to get away with using the same channel as my 0-10V measurement

Comment: And you can. Just feed the output of the I-to-V converter into that channel.

Comment: A resistor is an I to V converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly the way it is done on most PLCs including big names such as Allen-Bradley, etc.

Most that I have seen seem to use a 250 Ω resistor which will generate 5 V at 20 mA. I suspect that this is a compromise that while it reduces the resolution to 0.5 of full scale (1-bit) it also reduces the voltage drop at the device input leaving an extra 5 V for loop-powered devices.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDrAs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A typical 4 - 20 mA PLC input.*

With this arrangement there is 19 V available for the loop to cover voltage drop on the cables and whatever voltage the transmitter requires.

If your transmitter is self-powered then 500 Ω would be fine and give you maximum resolution. See [TE Connectivity UPW50 Series Wire Lead Wirewound Resistor 500Ω ±0.1% 0.5W ±3ppm/°C](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/through-hole-fixed-resistors/2173239/), for example, which seems to be specifically for this purpose.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG52lJ.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A self-powered or externally-powered transmitter may be better able to provide the 10 V output required to drive 20 mA into 500 Ω.*

> It is ok if I am not supplying the sensor from my device (as shown above with the 24 V)? As long as that sensors ground is connected into my input (as it is through my bnc connector)?

Yes, as long as the device can drive its output up to 10 V. This wouldn't be possible if, for example, the device was powered from a 9 V supply. You need to check the likely transmitters.

Comment: It is ok if I am not supplying the sensor from my device  (as shown above with the 24V)? As long as that sensors ground is connected into my input (as it is through my bnc connector)?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: sweet this is exactly what I needed. thx bro

Comment: It does assume a common ground though ..

Comment: Thanks, Robin. I've edited Figure 2 to make that unambiguous.